# 'Invalid datat type in MPI_Type_Struct . The program compiles but when running it gives the above mentioned error

Tags: c++, mpi, user-defined-types

I'm creating a struct and i need to scatter the array of custom made data types to do a calculation. I'm trying to create a struct of colour light which has 7 parameters. There are 5 lights which sends signals of traffic every 5 minutes. After an hour with it's 60 reading , the most congested area is calculated.I'm currently having issues with creating the user defined data types. If there are much better and productive ways of doing this task , suggestions are welcome

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stddef.h>

#define size 5     //number of Colour lights

using namespace std;

struct Light{
    int id;
    int traffic;
    int hour;
    int min;
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

int count = 0;

//const int size = 5;

Light lights[size*12] = {0};


int main()
{
/*
    //writing sample data to the file

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("trafficInfo.txt");

    int a = 0;
    int mini = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size * 12 ; i++){

        if(a == size)
            a = 0;


        if(mini == 59)
            mini = 0;

        outfile << a <<"        "<< (a+1)*10 << "   11  " << mini << "  3   " << "  6   " << "  2019" << endl;

        mini++;
        a++;
    }

    outfile.close();
*/
    MPI_Init(NULL , NULL);

    int numP = 0;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &numP);

    int rank = 0;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &rank);

    int elementsPerProc = ((size*12)+numP)/numP;

    Light gatherLights[elementsPerProc] = {0};



    if(rank == 0)
    {      
        ifstream theFile("trafficInfo.txt");

        int lId , lTraffic , lHour , lMin , lDay, lMonth , lYear;

        int cc = 0; //to increment the array by 1 every iteration

        while(theFile >>lId >> lTraffic >> lHour >> lMin >> lDay >> lMin >> lYear)
        {
            Light tempLight;

            tempLight.id = lId;
            tempLight.traffic = lTraffic;
            tempLight.hour = lHour;
            tempLight.min = lMin;
            tempLight.day = lDay;
            tempLight.month = lMonth;
            tempLight.year = lYear;

            lights[cc] = tempLight;

            if(count == size)
                    count = 0;

            cc++;
            count++;

        }

        int numEls = size * 12;

        int blocklengths[7] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
        MPI_Aint offsets[7] , extent;
        MPI_Datatype types[1];

        types[1] ={MPI_INT};
        types[2] ={MPI_INT};
        types[3] ={MPI_INT};
        types[4] ={MPI_INT};
        types[5] ={MPI_INT};
        types[6] ={MPI_INT};
        types[0] ={MPI_INT};

        MPI_Datatype mpi_Light;

        offsets[0] = offsetof(Light, id);
        offsets[1] = offsetof(Light, traffic);
        offsets[2] = offsetof(Light, hour);
        offsets[3] = offsetof(Light, min);
        offsets[4] = offsetof(Light, day);
        offsets[5] = offsetof(Light, month);
        offsets[6] = offsetof(Light, year);

        MPI_Type_create_struct(7 , blocklengths , offsets , types, &mpi_Light);
        MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_Light);

        Light recv[elementsPerProc];

        MPI_Scatter(&lights , elementsPerProc , mpi_Light , MPI_IN_PLACE ,elementsPerProc, mpi_Light , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        cout << "Rank is :" << rank << endl;


        MPI_Gather(MPI_IN_PLACE, elementsPerProc, mpi_Light , &gatherLights , elementsPerProc, mpi_Light , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else
    {
        MPI_Scatter(NULL , elementsPerProc , MPI_INT , &lights ,elementsPerProc, MPI_INT , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        cout << "Rank is :" << rank << endl;

        MPI_Gather(gatherLights, elementsPerProc, MPI_INT , &gatherLights , elementsPerProc, MPI_INT , 0 , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "`#define size 5`" - Why a macro and not a proper `const` or `constexpr` variable? The preprocessor is a necessary evil that should be used as sparingly as possible.

Comment: `offsetof` takes a type as its first argument. `lights` is an array, not a type.

Comment: @molbdnilo yeah that was the issue . duh! But now I'm getting an error saying that the data type used in MPI_Type_struct is invalid

Comment: You should first fix all the warnings reported by the compiler. `MPI_Scatter()` and `MPI_Gather()` are collective subroutines, and must hence be invoked by **all** the ranks of the communicator.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yup I have edited and updated the code for the latest state. I'm having two issues. One is with the first parameter of the MPI_Type_struct and the second is whether to use scatter or MPI_Send. Thank You.

Comment: what is your issue with `MPI_Type_create_struct()` ? you cannot have rank 0 scatter/gather `elementsPerProc` `mpi_Light` and other ranks scatter/gather the same number of `MPI_INT` (signature do not match and bad things will happen). You'd rather have all the ranks execute the same code.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet What im trying to do here is , using rank 0 I'm trying to read the data in the text file to the array 'lights'. And then I want to scatter that array and do a  multiplcation and find the highest value in the scattered array blocks.

Comment: but what the issue *"with the first parameter of the MPI_Type_struct"* you are having ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I was under the impression that the size of the data set was to be given there , when it really should be the number of block. (Which I assume is the number of processes)?

Comment: the parameter is the number of blocks used to create the derived datatype, and it is `7` here (and **not** `5`).

Comment: *number of blocks* is the number of elements in your `struct Light`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet ohh my bad. Got it . And the errors doesn't stop there. It now says there's and issue with the recv buffer of the scatter function!! :ugh

Comment: read my previous comment, also you should use `MPI_IN_PLACE` in **all** ranks (well, that won't be an issue if you run the same code for communications on all ranks ...). last but not least, the buffer is really the address of the first element.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I have updated the code to the latest state on this thread. The code compiles and runs but does not give an output. Instead runs in to an infinite loop of nothing.